# Check if current user has a especific value on a profile field

Tags: php, buddypress

I have a site with buddypress and I need to check if current user has a specific value on specific field

I was trying this but it's not working

```
 <?php 
$data= bp_profile_field_data( array('user_id'=>get_current_user_id( 'ID' ))); 
 if($data=='Funny Guy') {
  echo 'yes';
} else {
  echo 'no';
}
?>
```

Any hints why?

Answer (score 1):

Try using `bp_get_profile_field_data` instead and provide the name of the field you need. So:

```
$args = array(
    'field'   => 'Your field name', // Exact field name or field ID.
    'user_id' => bp_loggedin_user_id() // ID of logged in user
);

$data = bp_get_profile_field_data( $args ); 
if ( $data == 'Funny Guy' ) {
    echo 'yes';
} else {
    echo 'no';
}
```